# Craft a file that ignores all writes without being marked as read-only

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

*(Ubuntu 11.04.)*

I'd like to work around a configuration limit a certain service that writes an append-only file.

I'll have that file mounted from a remote machine (say, by NFS, can change this). I want to trick the program that uses the file on a local machine, into thinking that it can successfully append to the said file without letting it to do that.

The file should ignore all local writes (without triggering errors). The file should update robustly if a remote source changes (so if a service suddenly restarts, it will read actual data).

Any clues? Is there a robust solution to this?

Comment: Can't you simply use /dev/null as an output file for this program?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The whole point of this feat is to ensure that if the program (actually a continuously running service) restarts, it has actual data to load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Linux expert, so this may not be the most efficient solution, but it would be possible to write a small command-only program (hidden from user view) that monitors the file, un-doing any changes to it as soon as they occur. This same program could scan the remote source and apply the necessary changes/updates when they occur.

Comment: Looks not robust enough...

Answer (score 0):

If your application is dynamically linked, you can use [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LD_PRELOAD) to override the glibc `write` and `open` calls with custom `write` and `open` functions that can ignore any errors when trying to `open` a specific file for appending (or force it in read only mode), and `write` can also just return success without writing anything out (for that one file only of course).

There is also [liboverride](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/liboverride/) that I have never used, but seems like it can make this a little easier for you.

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you. Looks like a way to go, unless there is a ready-made solution of some kind.